# How do I add a git submodule located in another repository?

Tags: git

I added a git submodule from a 3rd-party remote repo to my project. It updated the .gitmodules file, which I then pushed to my remote repo. Now when I clone my project from my remote repo, I still don't see the new submodule. I DO see the new .gitmodules, but that's it. Even running "git submodule update --init" doesn't help. The only thing that works is adding the submodule again (with git submodule add...).

How do I permanently include my new submodule so that it is cloned automatically with the rest of my project?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

`git clone --recurse-submodules` should do the trick.

You can also do `git submodule update --init --recursive` to init submodules if you already did the clone.

Comment: I was afraid somebody was going to suggest this... because it didn't work when I tried it. :(

Comment: @BarryFruitman What does "not work" mean? What is the error, if any? What is the output of `git submodule` at the original and the cloned repository?